# Cordova commands are not working after is installed using npm

Tags: cordova, npm

I am trying to install cordova using npm using the following command

```
npm install -g cordova
```

It installed many files.But while checking the version using `cordova --version` it shows nothing.
[image]

My npm version is 3.7.2.

What might be the error?How can I solve this?

When i check with 'npm info cordova',it is showing like this[image]

I am using windows 7 system and my java version is 1.8.

Comment: What do the following commands show `npm ls -g --depth=0` and `npm ls -g cordova --depth=0` ? Is there an error ?

Comment: @topheman after the first command it is showing the following message,
+-- connect@3.4.1
+-- cordova@6.0.0
+-- cordova-lib@6.0.0
+-- gulp@3.9.0
+-- http-server@0.8.5
+-- ionic@1.7.14
+-- lite-server@1.3.2
+-- npm@3.7.2
+-- npmconf@2.1.2
+-- open@0.0.5
+-- phonegap@5.5.0
+-- tsd@0.6.5
`-- typescript@1.7.5

npm ERR! error in C:\Users\Anu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_module
s\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:
\Users\Anu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\node_mod
ules\dateformat\package.json'

Comment: @topheman  for second command it is showing +-- cordova@6.0.0
`-- phonegap@5.5.0